# Play background music for 24 hours (sleep music app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I am working on a "**Sleep Music**" app, where the user can play some soft music for a specific amount of time and the music will stop after timer runs out.

**Issue:**

The background music stops playing if the sleep timer is set to 10-12 hours without any errors or callbacks.

**Code to play music for the specific amount of time:**

```
 NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tickle_1sec" ofType:@"mp3"];
 NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
 _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
 _audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = noOfSeconds; //Loop it in such a way that music will stop playing when sleep timer has finished
 _audioPlayer.delegate = self;
 _audioPlayer.volume  = 0.1;
 [_audioPlayer play];
```

**Code to set AVAudioSession:**

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

The above code works fine if I set the sleep timer to 4-5 hours. I would appericiate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic.

Comment: go to capabilities background modes and turn audio  mode check box unchecked to checked.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already turned on the required capabilities. I am suspecting that this issue is happening due to interruptions.

Comment: no you are in need to add this audio timer in main run loop :)

Comment: and instead of setting number of loop to second set it to  -1 too so it will not stops